# Javascript convert array of numbers with duplicates into unique sets of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have a javascript sorting algorithm problem which I am struggling to solve efficiently .

I have an array of numbers which I am calling cards e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Each day I have **6 teaching sets**. In each set I want to display a maximum of 5 **RANDOM & UNIQUE** cards. Each card must be displayed **exactly 3 times a day**.

What I have done so far is to create 6 empty arrays (sets). I then iterate through my cards 3 times each attempting to add them to a random set if the card does not already exist in that array. Sometimes it works, but most of the time I get a problem where I have only one array with space left and that array already contains the card. my code:

Assume in my code that numberOfSetsPerCard = 3 & totalSets = 6. The only library available is JQuery.

```
shuffleIntoSets : function(cards, numberOfSetsPerCard, totalSets) {
        var sets = [];
        // initialize the sets as empty arrays
        for (i = 0; i < totalSets; i++) {
            sets[i] = [];
        }


        $.each(cards, function(index, card) {
            for(x=0;x<numberOfSetsPerCard;) {

                // attempt to place the card in a set which doesnt already contain the card
                setNo = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalSets));
                console.log("setNo: " + setNo);
                if(jQuery.inArray(card,sets[setNo]) == -1 && sets[setNo].length<5) {
                    console.log(setNo + "does not contain: " + card);
                    sets[setNo].push(card);
                    console.log("Added the card, set now looks like :" + sets[setNo]);
                    x++;
                }
            }
        });
        return sets;
    },
```

Comment: without reading too much into your code, does your code solve your problem?

Comment: it does on occasion. However for the majority the last remaining number cannot be placed in a set because 5 sets either already have 5 cards and the remaining card already contains the card I am trying to place therefore it cannot be placed. I am trying to figure out how to do this more efficiently also, as I feel I maybe missing something in terms of libraries available etc. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose to simplify my problem, if I had an array: [10, 5, 11, 3, 5, 12, 7, 8, 4, 8, 10, 11, 4, 7, 12, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 3, 6, 9, 12, 11, 6, 5, 10, 8, 4], how can I chop this array into arrays of length 5 where all members of the original array are passed into the new arrays but each new array cannot contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to your problem, it is a bit long, but i think it a bit long, but it definitely creates randomness in the teach sets, and satisfy the conditions you have stated

codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyoaZy

html/include jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

js:

```
//-----------------------------------------------
//For this question on StackOverflow:
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192127/javascript-convert-array-of-numbers-with-duplicates-into-unique-sets-of-numbers
//-----------------------------------------------

var cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var numOfTeachingSets = 6;
var numOfUniqueCardsPerTeachingSet = 5;
var numOfCardRepetitionPerDay = 3;


var shuffleCards = function(cards, numOfTeachingSets, numOfUniqueCardsPerTeachingSet, numOfRepetitionPerCard){
  if(cards.length*numOfRepetitionPerCard != numOfTeachingSets*numOfUniqueCardsPerTeachingSet){
    alert("invalid param");
    return null;
  }

  //since each card is required to repeat numOfRepetitionPerCard times
  //the available choices should be numOfRepetitionPerCard times of the original deck of cards
  var availableCardChoices = cards.concat([]);
  for (var i=0;i<numOfRepetitionPerCard-1;i++){
    availableCardChoices = availableCardChoices.concat(cards);
  }

  //Record down items from [availableCardChoices] has been picked
  var choosenList = [];

  //Put 6 sets of unique cards into the result
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0;i<numOfTeachingSets;i++){
    result.push( pickOutUniqueNumberSet(availableCardChoices,numOfUniqueCardsPerTeachingSet, choosenList) );
  }

  //return the result - an array of [numOfTeachingSets] arrays
  return result;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Function:
// picks [cardsPerSet] number of unique item out of [availableChoices]
// each time an item is picked, this item is removed from [availableChoices]
//
// Important note:  The number of card repetition is not really meaningful
//                  because if each round of picking produces unique sets,
//                  then the number of card repetition condition will be
//                  automatically satisfied.
//-----------------------------------------------------------
var pickOutUniqueNumberSet = function(availableChoices, cardsPerSet, disabledChoices){
  if (cardsPerSet==0 || availableChoices.length==0){
    return null;
  }
  var choosenSet = [];
  var maxAttempts = 10000;  //these 2 counter are used to prevent infinite looping
  var attempts = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<cardsPerSet;i++){
    //items are choosen from [availableChoices] by their array index.
    var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * availableChoices.length));
    //repeatedly grab a random index from availableChoices till a unique one is selected
    //unique item is an item that is not repeated in choosenSet, and its index is not in disabledChoices
    while( (InArray(choosenSet, availableChoices[randomIndex]) || InArray(disabledChoices, randomIndex)) && attempts<maxAttempts){
      randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * availableChoices.length));
      attempts++;
    }

    //Add this item to the chooseSet
    choosenSet.push(availableChoices[randomIndex]);

    //Add this item's index to disabledChoices
    disabledChoices.push(randomIndex);
  }
  return choosenSet;
}

var InArray = function(array, itemToFind){
  for(var i=0;i<array.length; i++){
    if(array[i]==itemToFind){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


//---------- Test --------
var teachingSets = shuffleCards(cards, numOfTeachingSets, numOfUniqueCardsPerTeachingSet, numOfCardRepetitionPerDay);
for(var i=0;i<teachingSets.length; i++){
  document.write(teachingSets[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your approach. I'll give that a shot and let you know how it goes. As i think you guessed, I was hoping there was a much more simple way of doing it! Thank you for the effort, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: not a problem, the idea is basically to select one from the list and mark that item as selected. You can play with the first 4 variables in at the beginning of the code. but remember, listLength * repetition must be equal to numOfSets * numPerSet

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Whilst as you say its a complex solution, it works like a dream and is well beyond my ability to think up a better solution.

Comment: Cheers, The code is not perfect, on top of my head there are ways to shorten the code and make it work more effectively. The above code merely shows 1 way of doing that. If you have gigantic lists, you may need to consider using global cardlist such that whenever you pick an item, that item is removed from the list. The code sample I provided have fatal performance issues for huge input lists.

Comment: Thankfully my application requirement that at any one time, the most cards is 10 and the max sets per day is 6. I spent a long time searching through jquery and other libraries in the hope of finding a way to break down the problem a little. I'm not particular good at algorithms hence my need for your help.